# How do I clear out dlopen()'ed shared libraries? Will exec() drop them?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, exec, posix

One of the libraries that I `dlopen()` hides globals that can only be set once after the `dlopen()`, and unloading .so's is optional according to POSIX so `dlclose()` is insufficient.

I would prefer just to reset the .so to its freshly-loaded state: is there a way to reset the .so to an unloaded state?

If not, will `exec(argv,...)` unload the symbols and libraries mapped by `dlopen()` before re-running the same program, or do they remain?

Comment: Just to clarify, `dlclose` does not remove loaded library in your case because it provides symbols used by other libraries? And you need some guaranteed way to somehow unload it? Note that `exec()` effectively replaces your program with a new one so _all_ state is dropped so it's probly an overkill in your case.

Comment: Ya, I know that dlclose() doesn't cleanup as I would like.  I was thinking of prompting the user for "click to restart after making this change" so exec would kind of solve it, but I would like to find a better way.